# Made new GA1-3 web doesnt show data from GA4 app to get custom alert. How to share google analytics collected views across properties of same domain?

Tags: google-analytics

To where it applies- i think stackoverflow.com since questions about google analytics is here questions also.

So since GA4 somekind new system didnt had view panel and in GA4 cant add view panel or remake it, then i needed to make new property of same domain.
How can i share statistics (views) of existing property to new remade properties and remove old property?

No view panel to add alerts

[image: No view panel to add alerts]

Making new property with same domain with advanced setting to make old way

[image: Making new property with same domain with advanced setting to make old way]

This top one is the one with view options and alerts working but no data. How to migrate date to this?
[image: This top one is the one with view options and alerts working but no data. How to migrate date to this?]

Now new property of old type has view panel and can make custom alert
[image: Now new property of old type has view panel and can make custom alert]

But cant make analytics data to be shared across both items. How to migrate one old to other new or share betweeen allready collected views?

Answer (score 1):

You can manage httpd with "devops" related software like ansible, puppet or chef.